# When i build and run my app i don't have any problems, but when i archive i have error

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

My parameters are

Library setup method: CocoaPods
library: https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk
Version of the library: 7.0
Xcode version. Example: 8.3.3
OS version: iOS 9.0

My podfile is

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myAppName' do
pod 'Alamofire', '> 4.0'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '> 2.12.0'
pod 'moa', '> 8.0'
pod 'Auk', '> 7.0'
pod 'AZSClient'
end
```

When i build and run the app in iphone, i don't have any problems, but when i try archive the solutions for submit in the itunes connect i have various error:

Value of type 'UIScrollView' has no member 'auk'
Use of unresolved identifier 'Moa'

I tried remove this library from podfile and install with Carthage, but i have the same result.
Can help me

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the workaround has a serious downside:
Setting the Strip Linked Product setting to NO creates an archive that will not validate when uploaded to iTunes Connect for validation by Apple.
I got a message saying the binary had issues:

Non-public API usage:
The app references non-public symbols in Lisa: __tlv_atexit
I advise you to keep a copy of Xcode 7 if you need to submit a new binary to iTunes Connect!